# How to fix a frayed cable on a MagSafe Power Adapter?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

Any idea how to fix the broken plastic/rubber covering of the cable on a MagSafe Power Adapter? Mine is showing the inner wires and I'm afraid of getting an electrical shock.

Comment: Depending where exactly the cable is split and if the wires are not actually broken then you could choose to wrap it well with electrical tape or just purchase a new one.  IIRC There  was a replacement program at one time concerning an issue with the MagSafe Power Adapter cable fraying prematurely.

Comment: @user3439894 They may still give you a free replacement if you go the Apple Store.

Comment: @kittycat3141, I'm not the one with the defective MagSafe Power Adapter, Jade is.

Comment: @user3439894 I know, I was just responding and saying they'll do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually there will be very light electricity shocks, I fixed all my cables with this tape it is very strong an the with ones are more esthetics for mac white cable.

It's called RESCUE TAPE Self-Fusing Silicone Tape ~ WHITE. I got mine from Amazon but there might be other places or similar tapes.

[image]

Comment: That is a great idea, since I tried to fix it in apple store. My MAC is not in warranty anymore.... thanks a lot...

Comment: This is a common type of electrical-work tape, called self-fusing or fusion tape.  It is available in rubber or silicone varieties, and some variant ought to be in most hardware stores.

Answer (score 14):

[**Sugru**](https://sugru.com/blog/14-apple-life-hacks) - not cheap, but very good.

Goes on like Plasticene/Silly Putty, dries like rubberised plastic. Flexible & waterproof, lots of different colours.

[image]

[image]

Comment: where can I buy this ones? tried on amazon does not match any search :(

Comment: @Jade, Not sure how you searched Amazon for it, however it's there. [Amazon Search for Sugru](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Sugru)

Comment: You can also buy it direct from Sugru, at least in the UK. It's £13 for a pack of 8 sachets. One or two sachets should probably do all the jobs you see above; they're quite small but once open you need to use it or it will set overnight. It lasts longer than the sell-by date if you keep it in the fridge.

Comment: I can vouch for Sugru too, I've used it to repair cables, make identical flash drives identifiable for my blind brother-in-law, and more.

If you order from https://sugru.com/buy , they have a distribution center in Michigan that they'll ship from. I think ThinkGeek may also carry it.

Comment: This was not a good fix for me. The Sugru cracked where the cord meets the power brick. Sugru is just too brittle.