# MacBook Pro Power Supply Options

Tags: macbook-pro, power, magsafe

We seem to have a lot of problems with genuine Apple power supplies for our MacBooks failing at the spot where the cable enters the case. So I've got some questions:

- Suggestions for best practices for keeping the power supplies alive?
- Are there alternative power supplies that are either more robust or more repairable (either from Apple or from third parties – for example are the original MagSafe supplies more durable than the MagSafe 2, or vice versa)?

I'm getting tired of replacing these technological wonders…

Our failures are worse than shown in [How to fix a frayed cable on a MagSafe Power Adapter?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234110/how-to-fix-a-frayed-cable-on-a-magsafe-power-adapter) when we notice them… The current one is at the point where I can't reliably get the cable into a position where it works – which is what I think it would take for the methods suggested in the answers to this question to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix a frayed cable on a MagSafe Power Adapter?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234110/how-to-fix-a-frayed-cable-on-a-magsafe-power-adapter)

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks for the link, but our current supplies are farther gone than that…

Comment: If the actual copper core has gone, then your only fix is to take them apart, clip beyond the fray & re-attach. [Whether this is easy or not depends on the construction, I've never got one into that state]. I would suggest pre-emptive Sugru in future. I've never lost a sugru'd cable yet.

Comment: this probably needs to be closed to focus on either a) how to prevent damaging (and we'd need to know exactly how yours are being used and failing - is it a 10 year old school deployment where children aren't being taught to care for their equipment) b) Does anyone make equivalent items? (again - knowing how yours fail and your budget would help. If you buy hundreds a quarter, you could probably hire a factory in China to make them. If we're talking 10, the economics are elsewhere). c) DIY repair is a dupliacate question so I've edited that out already)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is probably going to be two things:

1. Institute a regular inspection program - don't wait until things break. When you notice users bending the cables two months after you issue them is when you need to train the users to not crimp/bend the cables (to budget for users that are hard on the equipment so you have spares on hand when they break them).
2. There are no aftermarket MagSafe adapters made to better specifications or materials than Apple's  - only cheaper knock off and imitation or just less solid but well designed and built. You would need to armor or stiffen the cables before they fail with added material if you don't want to train users.

If your users are breaking the accessories, you'll want to train them and explain how tightly wrapping or always bending the cord in the same exact spot will break down the materials faster than if they spread the bends across a larger area or just keep the bend radius larger as opposed to a sharp right angle bend.

- https://www.wired.com/2013/12/tnhyui-macbook-powercord-wrapping/

Note the loop and the straight cable on both the MagSafe end and the power brick end. Also, note that Apple has ditched this design in favor of easily replaceable USB C cords so people that are hard on cables won't need power adapters going forward - just cable replacements.