# internal damage to lightning connector

Tags: iphone, charging, hardware-recommendation

I use my iPhone a lot while the charging cable is plugged in. I keep damaging my lightning connector internally, I suppose, by bending it too much while connected to my iPhone. I go thru a lot of cables and have tried many different brands. Can anyone suggest a lightning/USB cable that may withstand this use better? The damage must be where the connector and cable are connected.

Comment: Try Sugru - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234114/85275 use it **before** the cables get weakened, not after.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Thanks,I may try that. I found it on Amazon.