# 2017 macbook pro shutting down

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

My 2017 13inch MacBook pro is randomly shutting down.  The battery is 82% or higher.  when I try to turn it back on I get a screen with a battery that looks like it needs charging.  I have to connect to power to turn it back on.  when I do this the battery has the same charge of 82%.
Is my computer dying after only 3 years?

Comment: Have you tried reseting the SMC of your mac? You can follow this guide to do so: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mac-shutting-randomly-heres-can/

Comment: Short answer - yes.  The expected life span of a battery is 3 to 5 years so you may very well be experiencing a battery that needs service.

Comment: See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/395811/119271 for info on battery life span