# How can I make iPod 30-Pin cables last longer?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

I am still using an iPod that has a 30-pin connector. 
I find the cables only last for 2-3 years before they start to fray and stop working.

I am buying a new cable and would like to know if there any tips to make it last longer.

I've never had any problems with any other type of cable. Some of my micro USB cables get used way more and are nearly 10 years old. It only seems to be the iPod cables that fray.

[image] [image]

Comment: Sugru - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234114/85275

Comment: @Testsujin For the cost of 1 packet of Sugru, I could buy 4 cables, which would give me 12 years of use. The iPod would probably be dead by then, so Sugru isn't ideal.

Comment: Upload a picture of the fraying you experience. We might be able to offer information on avoiding physical stress there. Hard to guess how yours are failing and there are tons of suppliers for these still for replacements.

Comment: @bmike Updated with photos.

Comment: Super helpful. I'll make an answer later once I look up part numbers for heat shrink tubing to extend the bend radius and you could pre-apply that on a couple new cables to make them much more hardy. It might even save the ones you have if they're still electrically sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question comes down to how the cables are treated over their life time.  This applies to pretty much all cables regardless of the manufacturer or type (USB, network, charging/power, etc.).  It's also important to note that Apple used a higher quality, more *flexible* cable (it feels softer and thusly, more premium in the hand).  The downside, it's not as durable the cheaper, more "plastic-y" cables.

### Coil your cables

The cable will have a natural "loop" to it and if you coil it following that loop you will preserve it for years to come.

- Follow the *natural* loop and coil your cables so that there's no strain on the adapter ends
- Do not bunch them up in a tightly wound loop and don't "fold" them over.
- Most importantly, never knot your cable into itself - it's not rope.

[image]

The photos above are of my actual *genuine* Apple 30 pin cable that must be pushing at least 10 years of age.  The top photo is the exact way that I store my cables even when traveling.

For reference, this is the exact same way I coil my cable on my Microsoft Surface Pro tablet that I keep in my briefcase.

[image]

### Use strain relief where possible

- Tie-wrap your cables in a bunch to prevent excessive strain being applied to the connector ends
- Use cable management gadgets to prevent the cables from going over sharp edges
- Use "service loops" judicially when routing cables behind a desk or furniture.  Loosely coiling the wire and *loosely* wrapping them with Velcro or plastic will allow for movement without binding on the connectors.

[image]

I've followed these practices for the better part of 20+ years (obviously not with just Apple cables) and can honestly say that I have a significantly greater likelihood of replacing a cable because I lost it versus it becoming damaged.

Comment: Can I use twisty cable ties (e.g. https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B074DRSVNL) or is it better to use the ties you have shown. Thanks for such awesome advice.